# Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd Gen, docked into a ThinkPad OneLink Dock. Dual Monitors flicker

Tags: windows-7, lenovo-laptop

Been having this issue, Lenovo X1 Carbon 3rd generation is docked into a ThinkPad OneLink Dock. Using two 22 inch ViewSonic external monitors. The external monitors will flicker. Some days they won't flicker at all, some days they will flicker 15 times in a minutes.

I have reinstall the video drivers, replaced the dock, replaced the DVI cords. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS:

From the BIOS changelog:

<1.11>
 UEFI: 1.11 / ECP: 1.06
- (Fix) Fixed a flicker issue on an external monitor via OneLink Pro Cable Dock.

FROM: http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-X-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-20BS-20BT/20BT/S0BT00/downloads/DS101975

Double check that the BIOS matches your machine etc. first.